# How can I send data in text field using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm having an issue when I'm going to send data in text field. I got an exception.

I'm using Firefox version 54.0b1 (32-bit) and Selenium 3.3.1.

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

The exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string

Comment: Can provide some more information as: 1. What are your testing steps? 2. What have you tried so far? Show code. 3. What worked for you? 4. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

you need to download the latest gecko driver for Mozilla Firefox 54.x and Selenium 3.x.

Also provide accurate path as follows:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\directory\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http:\\yoururl.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Raj its not working its still same issue and exception.

Comment: Try this line in your code:
`System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"false");`

Comment: Its still not working raj i think couple of days before i have changed my window 8 to windows 10 may be its big cause for this issue >??

Comment: OS does not cause to this kind of issues......
You can give another try by downgrading the Firefox version.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a Firefox issue and issue have been recorded. Go through the below link for more info

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1357661