# Automation Testing related query

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, web-applications, automation

Facing the below issue in Eclipse. Attached the logs. please help with your suggestions
1493505852004   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:32725
1493505852739   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\arora\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.ameyOkKY6RPS
1493505852744   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args []
1493505852744   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:53292
IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

#### !!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PLayerTransaction::Msg_ReleaseLayer Processing error: message was deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)

IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

#### !!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PLayerTransaction::Msg_ReleaseLayer Processing error: message was deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)

[GPU 6784] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1493505857734   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53292
Apr 29, 2017 3:44:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'SAGAR', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\arora\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.ameyOkKY6RPS, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=6.3, moz:processID=6264, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: f85ef783-51ac-4d6b-a228-6835999ae465
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:98)
    at Gmail.main(Gmail.java:25)

Comment: Provide more info as: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3 Where are you stuck? 4. Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Blatantly putting all the log files is not going to make life easier for you.  Try to see what the error is about.

A quick search gives me the result that your `sendKeys()` operation performed for the test on Mozilla version 53.0 might be broken. A bug has already been filed with the Gecko developers for this - [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659) is the link for that.

Also, this seems to be the duplicate of this same question asked 4 days ago - [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603659/how-can-i-send-data-in-text-field-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

The Geckodriver is not working with the every version of Selenium.

You must have the last version of Selenium.